# Custom payment method like purchase order

Tags: module, magento-1, payment

I want to add my custom payment method say purchase order just clone of Payment Methods > purchase order,
means clone of purchase order with different name of how can I add two purchase order?

How can I make purchase order module, please tell if there already ready made link for that.

Comment: you need to log admin actions ?

Comment: try this https://github.com/firegento/firegento-adminmonitoring

Comment: Admin Actions Logging is a out-of-the-box feature of Magento Enterprise Edition but not included in the community edition.

Comment: lol... guys im not sure where he @mour mentioned anything about admin actions. Read the question....

Comment: @Shaughn, `mour` is a smart guy, he used 50 bounties to get resolved of his two requests one by one :), check his edit :)

Comment: @MTM dude read the comments from Pradeep and Anna. Then read mine. I am just clearly stating the obvious. mour's question mentioned nothing about admin actions, yet Pradeep and Anna both commented about something completely unrelated......

Comment: @Shaughn, mour's orginal request was what anna and pradeep replied, later the question was edited and changed, thats what i was trying to tell you :)

Comment: Ok, stupid me :( would help if i read the edit. TY

Answer (score 6, accepted):

have a look at https://github.com/luemic/Magento-Custom-PurchaseOrder which adds a second purchase order payment method. In fact most of the configration is copied from the original purchase method. However there must be a second method existing with it's own method code so it can be (de-)activated separately from the original method.